# OpenCV Sorting Contours by Area in Java

Tags: java, opencv

This is my first time working with OpenCV, I am having trouble figuring out a method to sort the contours by area. I am looking for the two largest areas. Currently I have:

```
 List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
 Imgproc.findContours(MatOut, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you considered the OpenCV function [`contourArea`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#contourArea(org.opencv.core.Mat)) ?

Comment: well I am confused on the methodology in which contours are stored in the ArrayList. So I wasn't sure on how to move them within the ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

For Java 8+

```
//finding max area
Optional<MatOfPoint> largest = contours.stream().max(new Comparator<MatOfPoint>() {
        public int compare(MatOfPoint c1, MatOfPoint c2) {          
            return (int) (Imgproc.contourArea(c1)- Imgproc.contourArea(c2));
        }
    });
// sorting 
contours.sort(new Comparator<MatOfPoint>() {
        public int compare(MatOfPoint c1, MatOfPoint c2) {          
            return (int) (Imgproc.contourArea(c1)- Imgproc.contourArea(c2));
        }
    });
```

For Java 7 use Collections.sort with same comparator and get the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively simple once I understood how it worked, simply apply a sorting method using `contourArea` as the key.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how to use this sorting method...
I am trying to sort the contours by their size in java ..
Belo is how I would do in python
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)